# How to recover the time (HH: MM) timestamp stored in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, datetime, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem
I am saving a datetime with:

```
created_at: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
```

I'm trying to retrieve the time, by reading each doc:

```
renderMensaje: function(msj) {
var date = new Date(msj.data().created_at * 1000);
// Hours part from the timestamp
var hours = date.getHours();
// Minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
date = hours + ":" + minutes;
// ...
```

But, it doesn't work right.

```
console.log(date); // => Wed Dec 31 1969 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (hora estándar central)

console.log(msj.data().created_at); 
// => Timestamp(seconds=1535222867, nanoseconds=351000000)
```

How can I get the time (HH:MM)?

Comment: Please mention what is it that is not working? Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more points

Comment: Looks like an Unix-timestamp. You can parse it into a Date object and from that get hours/minutes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/847196/7362396

Answer (score 0):

**Issue** - Firestore returns a [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) object

**Resolution** - Convert `msj.data().created_at` to [JS Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) using [toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#toDate)

---

**Code Snippet**

```
renderMensaje: function(msj) {
    var date = msj.data().created_at.toDate();

    // Hours part from the timestamp
    var hours = date.getHours();

    // Minutes part from the timestamp
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();

    date = hours + ":" + minutes;
}
```

> Also, check [MomentJs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/momentjs/info). It is a lightweight, simple date library for parsing, manipulating, and formatting dates.

Comment: Something is wrong:
console.log(date); // => Wed Dec 31 1969 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (hora estándar central)

Comment: This would be the result of `new Date(your_timestamp)`, use prototype functions on the `date` object as mentioned above.

Comment: `created_at` is a Timestamp object, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore stores dates in documents as a [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) type object.  If you want to get a Date object from a timestamp field in the document, you'll have to use its [toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#toDate) method to convert it.